# blank file created by program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program runs in a loop and generates file for the no of records listed in  info list. But for the last record in that list it's generating a blank file. The final_list is never blank, i check that but still every time the last file which is being created is empty. Can someone please tell what i did wrong?

```
outputC = net_connect.send_command("show int desc | i xe")
outputC1 = net_connect.send_command("show int desc | i xt")
final_list = capture_op(outputC,outputC1)
length = len(info[count][1])
name = info[count][1]     
name = name[0:length]+".txt"
for path,dirname,filename in os.walk("."):
    for file in filename:
        if file == name:
            os.remove(name)
            break
fo=open(name , 'w')
for i in final_list:
    print (i)
    fo.write(i)
    fo.write('\n')
fo.close
count+=1
```

Comment: You're not calling `fo.close`.

Call it like this: 

`fo.close()`

Comment: Thanks, im doing this same mistake a lot..

Comment: Use `with open(...) as ...:` and you shall worry not.

Answer (score 0):

As DeepSpace suggested you should really always use with open()

```
with open(name, 'w') as fo:

    for i in final_list:
        print (i)
        fo.write(i)
        fo.write('\n')
count+=1
```

Python Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files